# Circle Graphing Program

Tags: python, string, int, geometry

I am trying to make a program that graphs a circle using radius and center coordinates that the user inputs. This is what I have so far

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def circle(r,h,k,domain):
    x = np.array(domain)
    y = eval(np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2) + k)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show

rad = input("Radius: ")
xcen = int(input("Center X Coordinate: "))
ycen = int(input("Center Y Coordinate: "))

circle(rad,xcen,ycen,np.linspace(-10,10,500))
print("Done")
```

When I run it I get an error concerning the line `y = eval(np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2) + k)`

```
Radius: 5
Center X Coordinate: 0
Center Y Coordinate: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Science/PYTHON3/Circle.py", line 13, in <module>
    circle(rad,xcen,ycen,np.linspace(-10,10,500))
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Science/PYTHON3/Circle.py", line 5, in circle
    y = eval(np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2) + k)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
>>>
```

What does this mean? Why is it saying `str` and `int` can't be used with `**`

Comment: *"Why is it saying `str` and `int` can't be used with `**`"* - Well what would you expect `'foo' ** 3` to produce?

Answer (score 3):

```
rad = input("Radius: ")
```

In Python 3.X, the result returned by `input` is a string. That string is then passed to `circle`, which you try to square. But you can't square a string.

Convert `rad` to a number before using it.

```
rad = float(input("Radius: "))
```

Comment: Can I still use int for that in 3.X or is float better?

Comment: You can use `int`, but the user won't be able to enter a fractional radius like "1.5".